# How to change size of popover field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ field.label_tag }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle popover-body helper-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"
            data-toggle="popover"
            data-trigger="hover"
            data-content="{{field.help_text}}">
            </i>
        {% endif %}
    </label>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8feMc.png)

How can I change the size of that helpertext's value? I want it to be more wide. I tried doing something on class, but it only affects helper placement. Something like text wrapping or similar would be perfect, but I can't find it in documentation. Is that even possible without external libraries?

Without control-label in class, I don't have good placement of label, but then at least field text of helper is not so narrow.